# How can I change the `AUTHORIZE ACCESS` button in a Google Apps Script based Google Workspace Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am develloping a Google Apps Script based Workspace add-on.

I am trying to figure out how to edit the `AUTHORIZE ACCESS` button to match [Google's Sign-In Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page).

I've searched high and low and don't see anything that talks about how to edit the sign-in experience for add-ons.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue. Does your button already look like in the screenshot you provided? In this case it already matches the guidelines. What exactly would you like to change compared with what is visible in the screenshot?

Comment: Right now, according to Google, that button does not meet their guidelines. It needs to match what is in https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page) apply to buttons that you create yourself.
- The `AUTHORIZE ACCESS` button under the text

> Would you like to give this add-on access to your account?
> This add-on would like to show additional information in Gmail, but it needs approval to access your Google account.

is a standard Google interface that typically appears when you test an Add-on deploying it from the Apps Script editor

- The above mentioned screen cannot be modified in any way, since it is being generated by Google.
- In any case, when an Addon is installed from [Google Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace), opposed to being tested locally, the authorization prompt will occur in a pop-up window during the installation process, rather than within the sidebar of the Add-on.

Comment: Do you know where this is officially documented? I am going through the OAuth consent screen review/approval process and the Google folks are saying I have to make the  `AUTHORIZE ACCESS` match the branding guidelines and, as you stated, I can't.

Comment: I think those [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page) apply to a `mobile or web app` - as it states, not to Addons.  I have not encountered any issues publishing Addons without modifying the standard Google `Authorize Access` UI. Did you get a comment from a reviewer asking you to modify anything? In this case: ask him for more details - maybe there is a misunderstanding?